# Jenkins: set environment value from script block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins: set environment value from script block possibly without using intermediate files.

Job looks like:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
   environment {
   file_path = "old/path"
   }

  stages {
    stage("stage1") {
      steps {
        echo "Hello there!"
    sh '''
    NEW_PATH="/some/new/path"
    '''
    //How to assign  NEW_PATH to file_path so below 
    //print stmt provides output "/some/new/path"
        println file_path   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried something like

```
file_path = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo ${NEW_PATH}").trim()
```

it didn't help.

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to do here?

Comment: You can't overwrite exist variable inside `env` object, but expand by new variable name like `script { env.new_path=new/path/...}`

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I want to export variable with newvalue from `sh ''' ''` block - so that it can be re-used in different stages.   @yong okay will try your suggestions. thank you both for your responses.